# How to debug application as root in Geany on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, geany

Having installed Geany on a Raspberry Pi and added the Debugger plugin, I need the debugger to run the application as root as I am accessing the GPIO libraries and pins on the Raspberry Pi.

I usually run the program using sudo ./programName

I cannot find an option in the debug settings to prefix the debug target with sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running geany with `sudo geany`.